# How to have ShareX take a screen shot and automatically open MS Paint for further editing

Tags: windows

We have a laptop with ShareX and it is easy to take screen shots. On our desktop it automatically opens Paint. On the laptop it does not. Anyone know the proper settings? Thanks.

Comment: Compare the settings on the two computers.

Comment: ShareX has a decently clear interface for controlling what happens when you take a screenshot. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Are we able to choose a solution offered? We did get the screen shot saved to a ShareX folder. Thanks.